# URL Rewrite with parameter and php query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Directories:
 **eventfinder** is project folder

- Localhost
  -- project1
  -- project2
  -- **eventfinder**
  --- .htaccess

User comes to the page http://localhost/eventfinder/ and types 'randomevent123' after /eventfinder/

then php query happens with ?event=randomevent123

```
$event = $_GET['event'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE name = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $event);
$stmt->execute();
```

and returns data from database

I am trying to rewrite my url but I don't understand what is the problem...

```
http://localhost/eventfinder/index.php?event=randomevent123
```

to

```
http://localhost/eventfinder/randomevent123
```

With .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?event=$1 [L]
```

But query won't work.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^eventfinder/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?event=$1 [L]` you're not taking into account `/eventfinder/` at the moment.

Comment: @CD001 Nothing happened after I changed what you suggested

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^eventfinder/([^/]*)$ /eventfinder/index.php?event=$1 [L]`

Comment: ^ Oh yeah, I missed the `/eventfinder/` in the resulting path as well :\ ... unless `/eventfinder` is an actual directory and *that's* where the .htaccess file resides?

Comment: Nothing happens with http://localhost/eventfinder/randomevent123

Comment: /eventfinder/ is folder inside localhost
and .htaccess file is inside eventfinder

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)([^/]+)/?$ index.php?event=$1 [L]`

Comment: @Deadooshka, it is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Give the following a try:

1. Confirm that `mod_rewrite` is loaded
2. Check that [`AllowOverride`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/core#allowoverride) allows htaccess parsing
3. The following rule (inside `eventfinder` directory):

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /eventfinder/

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /eventfinder/index\.php\?event=([^\s&]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1 [R,L,QSD]

   RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php([^/]+))$ index.php?event=$1 [L]
   ```

Comment: I changed these settings from httpd.conf and restarted apache, still not working.

LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

I changed <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Apache version 2.4.25

Comment: @Troutfisher The `AllowOverride` needs to be activated for the directory of your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. I certainly hope that it is not `/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /eventfinder/index.php?event=$1 [L]
```

You can us `!-f` and `!-d` checks on the requested filename to ensure that the URL that's being typed is **not** a file and **not** a directory before doing the rewrite itself - it prevents a recursive loop on `index.php`